# MySQL delete of large records from large table Failed incosistantly

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

We are deleting the records from table which is older than one month by using the following query in python script(using MySQLdb library),

```
DELETE FROM emp_log WHERE path LIKE '%Common%' and timestamp <= "2016-03-25";
```

But, sometimes this delete query failed & we are not able to found the error from script as it didn't throw the exception.

Can anyone please tell us the possibility of this failure... Thanks...

Comment: This always fails since you forgot the quotes around the date `timestamp <= '2016-03-25'`

Comment: Thanks for your reply juergen,.. i forget to add the quotes while typing the query in the POST, now i corrected. But we used quotes when executing the query...

Comment: Since there is no error how do you know the query failed?